# Installation of python package amici - C compiler is not able to build a simple test program

Tags: python, visual-c++, cmake, compiler-errors, sbml

I'm trying to install the python package AMICI. I am following the tutorial in this page: https://amici.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_installation.html

I would like to use AMICI to generate a SBML problem in PyPesto using the PEtab format.

I am using Python 3.9 and have installed the MSVC C compiler available in Visual Studio Build Tools.

The following is the error I get when trying to install AMICI with the command pip install amici:

```
`
(venv) C:\Users\ana.valinhas\Documents\Python Scripts\MechanisticModelTransfectionPEtab>pip install amici
Collecting amici
  Using cached amici-0.18.1.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting cmake-build-extension==0.5.1 (from amici)
  Using cached cmake_build_extension-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy>=1.9 in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from amici) (1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: python-libsbml in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from amici) (5.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from amici) (3.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=2.0.2 in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from amici) (2.0.2)
Collecting wurlitzer (from amici)
  Using cached wurlitzer-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (7.3 kB)
Collecting toposort (from amici)
  Using cached toposort-1.10-py3-none-any.whl (8.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=48 in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from amici) (68.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from amici) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from amici) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cmake in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from cmake-build-extension==0.5.1->amici) (3.26.4)
Collecting ninja (from cmake-build-extension==0.5.1->amici)
  Using cached ninja-1.11.1-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (313 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: GitPython in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from cmake-build-extension==0.5.1->amici) (3.1.31)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools-scm in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from cmake-build-extension==0.5.1->amici) (7.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=2.0.2->amici) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=2.0.2->amici) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=2.0.2->amici) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas>=2.0.2->amici) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gitdb<5,>=4.0.1 in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from GitPython->cmake-build-extension==0.5.1->amici) (4.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from setuptools-scm->cmake-build-extension==0.5.1->amici) (23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from setuptools-scm->cmake-build-extension==0.5.1->amici) (4.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tomli>=1.0.0 in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from setuptools-scm->cmake-build-extension==0.5.1->amici) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: smmap<6,>=3.0.1 in c:\users\ana.valinhas\documents\python scripts\mechanisticmodeltransfectionpetab\venv\lib\site-packages (from gitdb<5,>=4.0.1->GitPython->cmake-build-extension==0.5.1->amici) (5.0.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: amici
  Building wheel for amici (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for amici (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [119 lines of output]
      running AmiciInstall
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running AmiciBuildPy
      running build_ext
      ------------------------------ SuiteSparse_config ------------------------------
      -- Building SuiteSparse_config version: v7.0.1 (Jan 20, 2023)
      -- Source:        C:/Users/ana.valinhas/AppData/pip-install-g2gatndu/amici_36641f72bf1a4f5eab8decde7d536cce/amici/ThirdParty/SuiteSparse/SuiteSparse_config
      -- Build:         C:/Users/ana.valinhas/AppData/pip-install-g2gatndu/amici_36641f72bf1a4f5eab8decde7d536cce/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-39/Release_SuiteSparse_config
      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.36.32534.0
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
      CMake Error at C:/Users/ana.valinhas/AppData/pip-build-env-aqngm_ut/overlay/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
        The C compiler
     
          "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"
     
        is not able to compile a simple test program.
     
        It fails with the following output:
     
          Change Dir: C:/Users/ana.valinhas/AppData/pip-install-g2gatndu/amici_36641f72bf1a4f5eab8decde7d536cce/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-39/Release_SuiteSparse_config/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-y0eyq7
     
          Run Build Command(s):C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Scripts\ninja.EXE -v cmTC_3f0da && [1/2] C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2022\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1436~1.325\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo   /DWIN
32 /D_WINDOWS  /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -MDd /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_3f0da.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_3f0da.dir\ /FS -c C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-install-g2gatndu\amici_36641f72bf1a4f5eab8decde7d536cce\bui
ld\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release_SuiteSparse_config\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-y0eyq7\testCCompiler.c
          [2/2] cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\cmake\data\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_3f0da.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.
0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2022\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1436~1.325\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_3f0da.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmT
C_3f0da.exe /implib:cmTC_3f0da.lib /pdb:cmTC_3f0da.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi
32.lib && cd ."
          FAILED: cmTC_3f0da.exe
          cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\cmake\data\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_3f0da.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\
rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2022\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1436~1.325\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_3f0da.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_3f0d
a.exe /implib:cmTC_3f0da.lib /pdb:cmTC_3f0da.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib
 && cd ."
          LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2022\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1436~1.325\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_3f0da.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj /out:cmTC_3f0da.exe /implib:cmTC_3f0da.lib /pdb:cmTC_3f0da.pd
b /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_3f0da.di
r/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_3f0da.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
          LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
     
          ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
     
     
     
     
     
        CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        cmake_modules/SuiteSparsePolicy.cmake:93 (enable_language)
        CMakeLists.txt:34 (include)
     
     
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      running AmiciBuildCMakeExtension
     
      ==> Configuring:
      $ cmake -S C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-install-g2gatndu\amici_36641f72bf1a4f5eab8decde7d536cce\amici\ThirdParty\SuiteSparse\SuiteSparse_config -B C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-install-g2gatndu\amici_36641f72bf1a4f5ea
b8decde7d536cce\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release_SuiteSparse_config -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-install-g2gatndu\amici_36641f72bf1a4f5eab8decde7d536cce\buil
d\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\amici -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Scripts\ninja.EXE -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DBLA_VENDOR=All -DENABLE_CUDA=FALSE -DNFORTRAN=TRUE
     
      ==> Building:
      $ cmake --build C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-install-g2gatndu\amici_36641f72bf1a4f5eab8decde7d536cce\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release_SuiteSparse_config --config Release
     
      ==> Installing:
      $ cmake --install C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-install-g2gatndu\amici_36641f72bf1a4f5eab8decde7d536cce\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release_SuiteSparse_config
     
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\Documents\Python Scripts\MechanisticModelTransfectionPEtab\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\Documents\Python Scripts\MechanisticModelTransfectionPEtab\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\Documents\Python Scripts\MechanisticModelTransfectionPEtab\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 416, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 401, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 175, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 159, in main
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 343, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-install-g2gatndu\amici_36641f72bf1a4f5eab8decde7d536cce\amici\custom_commands.py", line 124, in run
          self.run_command("build_ext")
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-install-g2gatndu\amici_36641f72bf1a4f5eab8decde7d536cce\amici\custom_commands.py", line 150, in run
          result = super().run()
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\cmake_build_extension\build_extension.py", line 113, in run
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-install-g2gatndu\amici_36641f72bf1a4f5eab8decde7d536cce\amici\custom_commands.py", line 177, in build_extension
          super().build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\cmake_build_extension\build_extension.py", line 229, in build_extension
          subprocess.check_call(configure_command)
        File "C:\Users\ana.valinhas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '-S', 'C:\\Users\\ana.valinhas\\AppData\\pip-install-g2gatndu\\amici_36641f72bf1a4f5eab8decde7d536cce\\amici\\ThirdParty\\SuiteSparse\\SuiteSparse_config', '-B', 'C:\\Users\\an
a.valinhas\\AppData\\pip-install-g2gatndu\\amici_36641f72bf1a4f5eab8decde7d536cce\\build\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\\Release_SuiteSparse_config', '-GNinja', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:\\Users\\ana.v
alinhas\\AppData\\pip-install-g2gatndu\\amici_36641f72bf1a4f5eab8decde7d536cce\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\\amici', '-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\\Users\\ana.valinhas\\AppData\\pip-build-env-aqngm_ut\\overlay\\Scripts\\ninja.EXE', '
-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON', '-DBLA_VENDOR=All', '-DENABLE_CUDA=FALSE', '-DNFORTRAN=TRUE']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for amici
Failed to build amici
ERROR: Could not build wheels for amici, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
`
```

Some troubleshoot I have tried so far:

- added the compiler's cl.exe location to the PATH variable
- added the windows 10 SDK mt.exe location to the PATH variable
- set the CC variable directly on pycharm to the compiler's cl.exe file.
- Installed/updated all dependencies for AMICI.
- Disabled the MAX_PATH length variable on the system.

When looking through the error it seems that CMAKE is unable to file a temporary file generated when running a test on the compiler.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? I would appreciate if anyone can provide some ideas on next steps.

Answer (score 0):

Error is due to path where build is happening is over the "standard" limit in windows.

No promises but you could try to enable long paths in Windows itself - some docs can be found here:  https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/filr/filr-4/filr-desktop/t47bx2ogpfz7.html

Or as alternative; you coud try passing `-b c:/buildtmp/` or or something similar to your `pip install`. This would place the actual build directory to almost root of your C drive so that when cmake generates the targets and tries to compile them - max path length limit wont be exceeded.

Comment: Hi @rasjani, thank you for your suggestion! I've tried disabling the MAX_PATH following this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=powershell I keep on getting the same error even though I check the "LongPathsEnabled" variable it is set to 1.
I've also tried adding -b (path in c: directory) to the pip install but I get an error that the command is not recognized. Is there something I'm doing wrong? sorry, maybe this is very a basic question!

Comment: I have an update on the installation. I've managed to change the directory where cmake is running the building command and the error regarding the max path length limit is not flagged anymore. 
However, the second part of the error is still flagged: "The C compiler is not able to compile a simple test program" and there is reference to cmake not being able to find the temporary target generated during the configuration/building process with the format "cmTC_xxxx".

Comment: Maybe update the log of the failure ?  In current version, there is no clear indication whats happening besides the fact that failure happens. Albeit the error is coming from cmake internal file, it could indicate that even you have installed MSVC - you might be missing some parts of it like Windows SDK - which, if missing most likely causes similar errors..

Comment: @anava do check out https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers and specifically the section "Compilers Installation and configuration"

Comment: Thank you @rasjani, I'll have a look through the link you've suggested. I've updated the log of the failure in the post.

Comment: --mt param in the call seemed a bit off and googling for that essentially points out some of necessary components are missing from MSVC installation. You might also need to call  "vcvarsall.bat" before your pip install *if* everything is actually available but cmake just cant find those ..

Comment: thank you per the tips! 
I've added the path to the windows sdk in the windows kits folder, so cmake can find mt.exe. I called the "vcvarsall.bat" on my developer command prompt per your suggestion.
Now I get a slightly different error: cmake is not able to find the kernel32.lib file. THis file is definitely in my pc as I have the windows 10 sdk installed. I've updated the error prompt in my post above. 
I think more than components missing from the MSVC installation, there's something wrong with the configuration of my environment... just not sure what exactly yet.